# Reserve a block of auto-increment ids in MySQL

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I receive batches of, say, 100 items that I need to insert into three related MySQL tables: say `current`, `recent`, and `historical`.  I want to insert each batch in each table as a group in a single insert statement for speed.  The `current` table has an auto-increment primary key `id` that I need to obtain for each inserted row and use as the primary key to insert the same row in the `recent` and `historical` tables.  My idea is to get the current auto_increment value for `current`, increment it by 100 using `alter table current AUTO_INCREMENT=`, then insert the 100 rows into `current` with programmatically set ids from the block that I just "reserved".  Then I can use the same 100 reserved id values for the inserts into the `recent` and `historical` tables without having to query them again from the `current` table.

My question: Is there some reason that this is a bad idea?  I have seen nothing about it on the web.  The closest I have seen on stack overflow is [Insert into an auto increment field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953312/insert-into-an-auto-increment-field) but that is not quite the same thing.  I can see possible threading issues if I tried to do this from more than one thread at a time.

I'm also open to other suggestions on how to accomplish this.

Comment: The purpose of the auto_increment is to provide a unique identifier for a record in a table. It would help if you could show your table structure and how these items are related. Your question is difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

There might be concurrency issues: If another connection inserts values between the time you get the current value and you set the new value, you would get duplicate keys.

I am not aware if that can happen in your situation, however, or if the inserts happen only from your batch described above, and there is never another instance of it running in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Methinks you shoud decouple the IDs from the 3 tables and using ALTER TABLE sounds very fishy too.

The most proper way I can think of:

- in `recent` and `historical`, add a colum that references to `current` ID; don't try to force the primary IDs to be the same.
- Acquire a WRITE table lock on `current`.
- Get the auto_increment value **X** for `current`.
- Insert your 100 records; their IDs should now run from **X**+1 to **X**+100.
- Release the table lock.
- Insert records in `recent` and `historical` with the know IDs in the extra column.

Note: I'm not sure if the auto_increment value points to the next ID, or the current highest value. If you use MAX(id) then you should use the code above.

Answer (score 0):

This is [a bit] late, but in case someone else has this same question (as I did):

As Ethan pointed out in his comment, auto_increment is an internal MySQL utility to produce unique keys. Since you have the ability to generate your own `id` values external to MySQL, I suggest removing the auto_increment overhead from the table (but keep `id` as PK, for transport to the other tables). You can then insert your own `id` values along with the data.

Obviously once you do this you'll have to program your own incrementing `id` values. To retrieve a "starting point" for each batch and maintain the speed of a single batch `INSERT` call, create another table (I'll call in `management`) with just a single record of `last_id`, which is equivalent to, but independent of, `max(id)` of your three primary tables. Then, each time a new batch is ready to be processed, start a transaction on `management` with a write lock, read `management.last_id`, `UPDATE` `management.last_id` to (`last_id`+1)+number in batch, then close the transaction. You now have sequential `id` values to insert that are reserved for that batch because any future calls to `management.last_id` will the next-larger set of `id` values.

The write-locked transaction removes any concurrency issues (as stated in FrankPI's answer) because any other processes attempting to read `management` must wait for the lock to be removed and will return the value *after* the `UPDATE`. This also removes the `id` ambiguity in JvO's answer: "...IDs **should** now run from X+1 to X+100", which can be a dangerous assumption.